# How to check if a parameter exists or not?

Tags: java, parameters, constructor, getter-setter, unboxing

So I have a video inventory program,

Where the user creates a object of the class video by initializing the constructor

```
Video video=new Video(String name){
this.name=name
}
```

Now I have three more parameterized constructor

```
Video video=new Video(String name, int rating){
this.name=name;
this.rating=rating;
}

Video video=new Video(String name, int rating, boolean checkout){
this.name=name;
this.rating=rating;
this.checkout=checkout;
}

Video video=new Video(String name, boolean checkout){
this.name=name;
this.checkout=checkout;
}
```

Each video added is stored in a `Video[] store` array

First the user adds the video only by passing the name *(eg.Matrix)* and creates the object of the video, it gets added in the `Video[] store`

What I want is that whenever a another parameter is added to *Matrix* , suppose `int rating`, it first finds *Matrix* from the `Video[] store` array, then checks whether the `boolean checkout` parameter exists or not.
if `boolean checkout` exists it passes the values to the constructor `Video video=new Video(String name, int rating, boolean checkout)`
else it passes values to the constructor `Video video=new Video(String name, int rating)`.

I want to know how to check if a parameter exists or not.

Another approach I wanted to take was to set one constructor `Video(String name)` and use null values to initialize the variables and later change them using *setters*, but you can't set `int` and `boolean` to null.
So I have to use it like this (as I found on the internet)

```
      Video(String name){
       this.videoName=name;
       this.rating=(Integer) null;
       this.checkout=(Boolean) null;
    }
```

but this requires unboxing or something which I have no idea how to do. So any help would be appreciated. :)

Comment: Constructors are made to construct objects, not to complete existing ones. A better solution would be to have a method that does the check/completion and call the constructor only if it's necessary

Comment: Rule number 1 in Object Oriented programming: model your things so that your abstractions are a good representation of reality AND useful. In your case: The name and rating of a movie ... is that going to change in the real world? Nope. Thus, and for many other reasons: strive to make your Video object **immutable**. Meaning: it should only have to (final!) fields name and rating. You set both fields using a constructor (the ctor checks that the incoming parameters are NOT null). And then your Video object NEVER needs to be updated again.

Comment: And then you could use another class that keeps a LIST of "existing movies" for example. And Another one that keeps a LIST of "existing movies that are currently rented". Believe me: allowing your Video object properties to be updated with setters is a BAD approach. Allowing properties to be NULL is also something you want to avoid.

Comment: And as said: keep concepts separated. A Video object doesn't know or care about its "rental" state. That is the responsibility of some sort of bookkeeper. And you also want to read a bit why/who you should implement/override the equals/hashCode methods in your Video class.

Comment: @GhostCat actually this a question given to me to solve for a college assignment, so as per requirements I can't make the variables final and I also need to include its rental state.
The other suggestions, I will keep them in mind. Thank you.

Comment: If you dare to be a brave student, ask your instructor why they teach you bad OO practices ;-)